# I use pdfbox PDFRenderer.renderImage render pdf to image failed. The result image is not same with which pdf shows

Tags: java, pdfbox

I use pdfbox PDFRenderer.renderImage  render pdf to image failed. The result image is not same with which pdf shows. Maybe some background colors are not rendered to image.
origina pdf file: [pdf address](https://github.com/zhongguogu/PDFBOX/blob/master/pdf/hk.pdf)

1. the expecting image:

[image: the expecting image:]

2. the actual output image is :

[image: failed image]

Comment: Probably a PDFBox bug in handling a grayscale JPEG with a separation colorspace. I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5778

Comment: Dagu, *"please help, thanks very much"* - for such details @Tilman definitively is the more appropriate person to address, I'm not really into the rendering stuff. And looking into your example file, his first guess seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was related to an unusual combination of gray JPEG, separation colorspace, ICC colorspace and LAB colorspace has been fixed in [PDFBOX-5778](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5778) and the fix will be part of the next versions (2.0.31 and 3.0.2). In the meantime, snapshot builds can be downloaded [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.31-SNAPSHOT/) (2.0.31) and [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.2-SNAPSHOT/) (3.0.2).